# How can I convert a vk constant to text?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to translate vk constants (possibly joined together) to their names (e.g., 81 (VK_CONTROL|VK_SHIFT|VK_A) = “Control+Shift+A.”
I tried using the GetKeyNameText function (both with vk and scancode constants), but it does not seem to work (the string is blank, it returns 0, and GetLastError returns 0 as well).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no API function that directly converts the combined virtual keys into text. For non-character keys (`VK_CONTROL`, `VK_SHIFT`, etc.), you need to manually concatenate strings.

For character keys, [`MapVirtualKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya) works fine for me.

I tested the code you provided:

```
UINT t = MapVirtualKey(VK_A, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);
```

I can get its return value:

[image]

Comment: Oops. I was using the return of MapVirtualKey(VK_A, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR) with GetKeyNameText, not realizing I can just convert to string instead.
Thanks for your help. I still find probably the most daunting task being trying to get them one by one, as that would require going through all VK codes and checking if their bit is set.

Comment: @NSstudios Could you explain why you need to check this way? If you just judge the state when the button is pressed, it seems that you don't need to judge one by one.

Comment: I'm trying to read a hotkey field from shortcuts and convert the numerical representation of keys to text. Would also be useful for hotkey GUI controls.

Comment: @NSstudios You may be able to use [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) to check the state of the virtual key.

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't really work for my primary goal: reading a shortcut/lnk file, getting its hotkey field, and translating its numeric representation of keys to text. I guessI'll have to just loop through all vk constants and find them one by one.

Comment: You can complete a preprocessing before reading, convert the corresponding virtual key code into text, and directly convert it when reading the hot key field.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the control and shift with

```
char keybuff[64] = {0};

if (keys & VK_CONTROL) {
  strcat(keybuff, "Control+");
  keys &= ~VK_CONTROL; // turn bits OFF
}
if (keys & VK_SHIFT) {
  strcat(keybuff, "Shift+");
  keys &= ~VK_SHIFT;
}
```

And use *MapVirtualKey* to map the VK code to a character

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya

So in the following case key becomes 65 which is the ascii value for capital 'A'. Cast it to a char and you have the letter. This works for all codes below ascii 127.

```
UINT key = MapVirtualKey(VK_A, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);
char c = (char)key; // 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping for more of an automatic solution for combined constants, but I cannot get GetKeyName to give me anything even if I do just VK_A, or map VK_A to character with MapVirtualKey(VK_A, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR). The buffer it's supposed to write things to is empty, even I did tell it to be 1024 bytes.

Comment: edited in how to use MapVirtualKey and clearing of control and shift bits

Answer (score 0):

I advise you not to use `GetKeyNameText` API at all since this an outdated shit that is [broken for non-US layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72464584/1795050). Create and use some lookup table youself instead. :)

If you still decide to use it then proper call of `GetKeyNameText` is tricky:

```cpp
// Get keyboard layout specific localized key name
std::string GetKeyNameTextWrapper(uint16_t scanCode)
{
    wchar_t name[128];
    int charCount = 0;

    // GetKeyNameText is not working for these keys
    // due to use of broken MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR under the hood
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72464584/1795050
    const uint16_t vkCode = LOWORD(::MapVirtualKeyW(scanCode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX));
    if ((vkCode >= (uint16_t)'A') && (vkCode <= (uint16_t)'Z'))
    {
        const uint32_t flags = 1 << 2; // Do not change keyboard state of this thread
        static uint8_t state[256] = { 0 };

        // This call can produce multiple UTF-16 code points
        // in case of ligatures or non-BMP Unicode chars that have hi and low surrogate
        // See examples: https://kbdlayout.info/features/ligatures
        charCount = ::ToUnicode(vkCode, scanCode, state, name, 128, flags);

        // negative value is returned on dead key press
        if (charCount < 0)
            charCount = -charCount;
    }
    else
    {
        const LONG lParam = MAKELONG(0, ((scanCode & 0xff00) != 0 ? KF_EXTENDED : 0) | (scanCode & 0xff));
        charCount = ::GetKeyNameTextW(lParam, name, 128);
    }

    return utf8::narrow(name, charCount);
}
```

Also note that `GetKeyNameText` will return different string according to string data that is sewn into keyboard layout dll. [And that layout dlls may have bugs](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2010/08/09/1950492.html).